# Increase check interval in BlobCache. Is there a way?

Tags: cache, blob-cache

As I rememeber - **BlobCache** checks page relevance every 5 seconds(not sure). Can I change this option? In web.config there is no such property in BlobCache string.

Because I have portal where data changes very rare, so I don't need to update cache often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for Change Check Interval (changeCheckInterval), which can be set through the web.config. I wrote an FTC solution for [management of the BLOBCache](http://blobcache.codeplex.com/) that covers this setting.

Comment: Hi Trevor! Yes, thank You very much, I found this key too now. I added it to  same string below enabled="true", don't know if it is right

Comment: It would look something like `<blobcache enabled="true" changeCheckInterval="9" />`. Add other elements, of course. The changeCheckInterval value is in seconds.

Comment: The order of the elements doesn't matter, so you can do it in any order you wish.